# get Dataframe from complex data structure using groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I need to plot this dataframe representation "types of infections by the state", the data looks like this, where 'T.categ' is the types of infection

```
       Unnamed: 0  state sex   diag  death status T.categ  age
0              1    NSW   M  10905  11081      D      hs   35
1              2    NSW   M  11029  11096      D      hs   53
2              3    NSW   M   9551   9983      D      hs   42
3              4    NSW   M   9577   9654      D    haem   44
4              5    NSW   M  10015  10290      D      hs   39
          ...    ...  ..    ...    ...    ...     ...  ...
2838        2839  Other   M  11475  11504      A     het   46
2839        2840  Other   F  11420  11504      A     het   34
2840        2841  Other   M  11496  11504      A    haem   49
2841        2842  Other   M  11460  11504      A      hs   55
2842        2843  Other   M  11448  11504      A      hs   37
[2843 rows x 8 columns]
```

So my code looks like this:

```py
data9 = data.groupby('state')['T.categ'].value_counts()

lines9 = data9.plot.bar(rot=0, title='types of infections by region')
lines9.set(xlabel='states', ylabel='amount')
plt.show()
```

but the data that I'm getting is not beautiful as I need it to plot it, the dataframe looks weird and the T.categ are working as rows and they are supposed to be columns, here is the result:

```
state  T.categ
NSW    hs         1539
       blood        70
       hsid         50
       other        42
       haem         30
       id           28
       het          18
       mother        3
Other  hs          204
       id           12
       het           8
       other         8
       haem          6
       blood         5
       hsid          4
       mother        2
QLD    hs          186
       blood        15
       hsid          7
       het           5
       haem          4
       id            4
       other         4
       mother        1
VIC    hs          536
       other        16
       hsid         11
       het          10
       haem          6
       blood         4
       id            4
       mother        1
Name: T.categ, dtype: int64
```

And is supposed to look like:

```
       hs  other  hsid .... mother
NSW   1539                   ...
Other  204
...
VIC    ...                    1
```

can somebody help me out please with this query... if not please check my other question, where I try to format my query to the needed dataframe, but still doesn't work...

Comment: `data9=data.groupby('state')['T.categ'].value_counts().unstack()`

Comment: maaan, I was looking for this the last 5 hours, big thanks

Comment: yeah buddy, just use .unstack() to bring up the infection types to columns. Let me know if you need more help on this.